# Can not create shared object from object files

Tags: makefile, shared-libraries, dynamic-library

I have wrote a makefile to compile a dynamic library. However, output .so file does not contains all of the methods.

I have used this Makefile:

```
CC=g++
CFLAGS=-fPIC -g
LDFLAGS=-shared
SRCDIR=src
SOURCES=$(shell echo $(SRCDIR)/*.cpp)
HEADERS=$(shell echo $(SRCDIR)/*.h)
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)

LIBDIR=lib
INCDIR=include

LIBRARIES=-lboost_filesystem -lboost_system -lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgproc
OUT=$(LIBDIR)/libAgeGender.so

all: $(SOURCES) $(HEADERS) $(OUT)

.cpp.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@ $(LDFLAGS)

$(OUT): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) $(LIBRARIES) -o $@ $(LDFLAGS)

clean:
    rm -f $(SRCDIR)/*.o *~ $(SRCDIR)/*~ $(OUT)
```

Then i executed this command to see functions inside of an .o file.

```
nm SDaisy.o | grep ' T '
00000000000070d6 T _ZN6SDaisy11convolutionERKN2cv3MatESt6vectorIfSaIfEEi
000000000000933e T _ZN6SDaisy12extractDaisyERKN2cv3MatE
0000000000007498 T _ZN6SDaisy14gaussianFilterERKN2cv3MatEff
000000000000854a T _ZN6SDaisy16smoothHistogramsERN2cv3MatE
000000000000c088 T _fini
0000000000005960 T _init
```

When we look into shared object, we can't see methods.

```
$ nm libAgeGender.so | grep ' T '
0000000000000578 T _fini
0000000000000438 T _init
```

How can i make it correctly?

Comment: Is this your real makefile? You seem to omit the `-c` in your `.cpp.o` rule. I don't see how it can work as written. Have you tried preparing a [minimal complete example](http://www.sscce.org/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the right variables and functions, and let `make` handle the compilation of `.o` files.

```
SRCDIR  :=  src
LIBDIR  :=  lib
INCDIR  :=  include

SRC :=  $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*.cpp)
OBJ :=  $(SRC:.cpp=.o)
OUT :=  $(LIBDIR)/libAgeGender.so

CXXFLAGS    :=  -fPIC -g
LDFLAGS     :=  -shared
LDLIBS      :=  -lboost_filesystem -lboost_system \
                -lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgproc

all:    $(OUT)

$(OUT): $(OBJ)
    $(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) $^ $(LDLIBS) -o $@
```